# How can I drag and drop files when there is no source directory?

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, directory, attachment

I have a little program that essentially moved files into a specific folder when the user drags the file into a panel. This works for anything that has a directory path. However, the software crashes if I drag an attachment from outlook into the panel.

(theoretical fix) Take the name of the file being placed into the panel, apply `File.Move(attachmentName, temporaryDirectory)` however, this seems messy.

```
private void panel2_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
}

public void panel2_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string destination = @"\\MAIL\DocupaceScans\fsnrep\FSNbp";

    string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);
    foreach (string file in files)

    File.Copy(file, destination + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(file));

    MessageBox.Show("Thanks!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the location of the outlook secure temp folder, which is at this location from Windows 7 and above,

> "C:\Users\ *< user >* \AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.Outlook\"

to implement it, use a try catch block and an if else statement to say where its should be coming from, so that you can catch your exception, and handle the error accordingly.

Comment: Awesome input, I'm sure I can inject [Environment.UserName] into that and try running it. Ill see if i can put that together.